# What is the difference between "to entail" and "to bring about"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, difference, synonyms

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/bring-sth-about?q=bring%20about) shows that

> **To bring sth about**  - to cause something to happen.
> *He brought about his company's collapse by his reckless spending.*

And

> **To entail** - to make something necessary, or to involve something.
> *Such a large investment inevitably entails some risk*

But when I translate it into my language(I know it's not a good idea), it seems to me, that these words are synonyms. So what is the difference?

Comment: what word in Ukrainian are you thinking about?

Comment: to me, to entail = to involve (тягнути за собою), and to bring sth about = to cause it to happen (вносити, спричиняти)

Comment: You can't entail a company's collapse. You cause it to collapse, you bring about its collapse and that will entail considerable effort.

Comment: @AndrewTobilko Anyway, it sounds very simmiliar

Comment: In your second one Such a large investment brings with it some risk (but not brings about).

Comment: I think trying to translate it into your native language is a good first step toward trying to understand a word; assuming that translation is perfectly correct is the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To ***bring something about*** actually ***causes*** something to happen (it's something that a conscious agent can deliberately do, as well as the possibility of, say, one situation X ***causing*** another situation Y).

But ***entailment*** doesn't work like that - it's a *logical relationship*, not something that a conscious agent can actually *do*. Either *Situation X entails Situation Y* or it doesn't (and if it *does,* we're simply saying that ***IF*** X happens / is true, ***THEN*** Y ***must also*** happen / be true).